# Embed 3d models and Images Visual C++ 2008

Tags: c++, visual-c++-2008, irrlicht

I'm using Irrlicht to make a game in C++ and I need to embed the models into my games .exe with Visual Studio 2008 Express(No Resource Editor) and load the models with Irrlicht. The problem is, I can't find any way to do this, no matter how much I research. Any ideas/solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How large are your models?

You *could* convert the binary (I'm assuming) files into ascii form as static data and load from that using a tool like bin2hpp.

http://code.google.com/p/bin2hpp/wiki/introduction

Is it a project requirement that the models be embedded in the exe?  Could you zip up all your game data into an archive and have two files?

Comment: yes, it is a project that requires them to be embedded, some of my models are from Turbosquid and they don't allow redistribution. Thank you this is exactly what I needed